# SMF on Nginx image bug

Tags: nginx, smf, simple-machines-forum

http://62-210.217.242/forums/

I have all the proper nginx conf and permissions, could anyone give me an insight on what might be causing this issue?

I have tried fixing it with
`location /forums {
try_files /forums/$uri/ /forums/$uri /forums/index.php;
}`

to no succcess. Thanks.

It appears that it fails to fetch images in the theme folder despite the fact that they are present.

Here are the full configs:

```
        server {
        listen 8080;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.php;

        server_name localhost;

        location /forums {
        try_files /forums/$uri/ /forums/$uri /forums/index.php;
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        #error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #}

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 16;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 5768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        server_tokens off;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;
        port_in_redirect off;
        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript;
        gzip_vary on;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log off;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location /forums {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /forums/index.php;
}
```

`$uri` variable already contains `/forum` prefix. There is no need to add it.